# keypress event getting triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my text area i am using this plugin https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js

and than i have the following code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function() {
      $('.pages .newcomment').autogrow();
     });

     $('.newcomment').keypress(function(event){
     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
     if(keycode == '13'){

  </script>
```

I have the following html

```
<textarea class="newcomment field span12" style="width: 350px; height: 20px; resize:none;  font-size: 60%"  placeholder="Enter comment here..." ></textarea>
```

I don' understand why there are two triggers because i can see the code execution comes twice in my keypress method...

Comment: Are you sure that you're not assigning the event handler twice?  Also you don't need to check "keyCode" and "which" - jQuery ensures that "which" is the key code.

Comment: actully keycode is for FF and which is for IE

Comment: Show how you are calling `$('.newcomment').keypress`

Comment: @SaurabhKumar you're using jQuery, and the event object your handler receives is not the browser native object.  Using "which" will work in all browsers.

Comment: I didn't understood u

Comment: Your code works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/f5suX/1

Comment: Again.... Show how you are calling `$('.newcomment').keypress` You might be somehow initializing it twice. We can not tell unless you show that code.

Comment: your fiddle dosen't work

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Look again, updated fiddle above with the function call that you missed in the code's question. You will have to share enough code to reproduce the issue otherwise this is not a real question.

Comment: I still understand what do u mean how u are calling. I have a text area with class newcomment and I have this jquery function bind to that class .

Comment: @SaurabhKumar if you are replying to someone add their name to your comment so we know you are talking to us. How is that code added to the page? Is it being called in onload, ready, click, Ajax callback, etc?

Comment: @FAB: i just add it as a script in my jsp page

Comment: Well ok, thing is, with that script it should still work fine. Your error is probably somewhere else. Try adding your code to the fiddle above until you see that it is not working as expected.

Comment: @FAB : I updated the fiddle. Could you tell me where is this console message printed

Comment: @SaurabhKumar On Chrome: Press F12 and check Console tab; Firefox: Either install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and press F12, Console tab or use FF's native console Ctrl+Shift+K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try keyup..

```
$('.newcomment').keyup(function(event){
 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13'){
    ...........
```